# Whitespaces error while coping files

Tags: command-line, duplicate-files

my needs is to copy all files and folders of a "master" folder into all the usb keys mounted.

So, i wrote this code:

```
for usb_key in `ls /media/`;
    do
        for file in `ls -a /home/daniele/USB/MASTER`;
            do
                cp /home/daniele/USB/MASTER/"$file" /media/$usb_key/"$file"
            done;
    done;

for usb_key in `ls /media`;
    do
        umount /media/$usb_key
    done;
#alert me that the work is done
totem /home/daniele/USB/0016.mp3 &
exit
```

But, if i have a folder named "DO NOT DELETE" into `/home/daniele/USB/MASTER`, this throw an error becose of the filenames.

So, how can i do solve that?
There is a way to replace all the whitespaces in the `$file` var with `\`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this? I don't know why you have to iterate each file and why you can't just copy the lot... But this should work slightly better than by parsing `ls`'s output.

```
for usb_key in /media/*;
do
    cp -Ra /home/daniele/USB/MASTER/* $usb_key
    umount /media/$usb_key
done;

#alert me that the work is done
totem /home/daniele/USB/0016.mp3 &
exit
```

Just to explain what's happening, for breaks on all spaces when parsing external input (as it was with your code). You can see that in operation by going to a directory with spaced files in and running:

```
for file in `ls -1`; do echo $file; done
```

In my TV directory, I see output like:

```
The
Big
Bang
Theory
The
Cleveland
Show
The
```

I think there is a way to change the break sequences but it's just easier to use bash's native file-finding syntax. Or use `find ... -exec ...` which is very powerful itself.